# understanding the fitting options of the statsmodels ARIMA.fit method

Tags: statsmodels, armax

I am trying to fit an ARMAX model to some data in python and I am not exactly an expert in the field and I'm having a hard time understanding statsmodels fitting options. By the way my statsmodels version is 0.14.

My question concerns the actual fitting options in [this](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit) documentation which I assume is the correct one (for some reason [this outdated documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/0.8.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit) continues to appear in my searches). There are 6 options :

- statespace
- innovations_mle
- hannan_rissanen
- burg
- innovations
- yule_walker

We're not told which option is used by default (the 'method' variable is optional) but we're told that yule_walker only works for AR processes and I have exogenous variables so we're left with 5 options.

I tried them all and 'Burg' is also incompatible with external input. hannan_rissanen and statespace gave me garbage but  innovations_mle and innovations gave me nice results. Here is the deal : what do these methods do? I guess hannan_rissanen, Burg and yule_walker are specific enough keywords so that I would get what they do but what about innovations, innovations_MLE and satespace?

I can imagine a few ways to fit ARMAX models but even if one is correct I would have no clue which one is which one.

Here any explanation, any online resources would be welcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.